# fine tuning word2vec on a specific article, using transfer learning

Tags: performance, nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec, transfer-learning

i try to fine tune  an exicting model on specific article. I have tried transfer learning using genism build_vocab, adding gloveword2vec to a base model i trained on the article. but the build_vocab does not change the basic model- it is very small and no words are added to it's vocabulary.

this is the code:
#load glove model

```
glove_file = datapath("/content/glove.6B.200d.txt")
tmp_file = get_tmpfile("test_word2vec.txt") 
_ = glove2word2vec(glove_file, tmp_file)
glove_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(tmp_file)`
```

*(in here - len(glove_vectors.wv.vocab) = 40000)*

#create good article basic model

```
base_model = Word2Vec(size=300, min_count=5) 
base_model.build_vocab([tokenizer.tokenize(data.text[0])]) 
total_examples = base_model.corpus_count`
```

*(in here - len(base_model.wv.vocab) =   24)*

#add GloVe's vocabulary & weights `base_model.build_vocab([list(glove_vectors.vocab.keys())], update=True)`

*(in here- still - len(base_model_good_wv.vocab) =   24)*

#training

```
base_model.train([tokenizer.tokenize(good_trump.text[0])], total_examples=total_examples, epochs=base_model.epochs+5) 
base_model_wv = base_model.wv
```

i think that the
"base_model.build_vocab([list(glove_vectors.vocab.keys())], update=True)"
does nothing- so there is no transfer learning.
any recommendations?

i relied on this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-with-glove-word-vectors-7652456ae269) for the guideline...

Answer (score 0):

Many articles at the 'Towards Data Science' site are very confused, to the point of misleading more than helping. Unfortunately, the article you've linked is a good example:

- The author first uses an unsupported value (`workers=-1`) that manages to make his local-corpus training do nothing, and rather than discovering & fixing that error, incorrectly concludes he needs to use 'transfer learning'/'fine-tuning' instead. (He doesn't.)
- He then tries to improvise a re-use of the GLoVe vectors, but as you've noted, his `build_vocab()` only manages to add the word-tokens to the model's vocabulary. This operation does *not* copy over *any* of the actual vectors!
- Then, by doing training in a model where the default `workers=3` was still in-effect, he finally does real training on just his own texts – no contribution from GLoVe values at all. He attributes the improvement to GLoVE, but really multiple mistakes have just cancelled each other.

I would avoid relying on a 'Towards Data Science' source if *any* other docs or tutorials are available.

Further, many who *think* they want to do re-use of someone else's pretrained vectors, with a small update from their own texts, should really just improve their own training corpus, so that they have one unified, evenly-trained model that covers all their needed words.

There's no explicit support for 'fine-tuning' in Gensim. Bold advanced users can try to cobble it together from other methods, and tampering with the model between usual steps, but I've never seen a well-characterized & evaluated process for doing so. (Lots of the people fumbling through the process aren't even doing a good check of end-quality versus other approaches, just noting some improvement on a few ad hoc, perhaps unrepresentative tests.)

Are you sure you need to do this? What was wrong with vectors taught on just your corpus? Might extending your corpus with extra texts to expand its vocabulary work as well or better?

Or, you could try translating the new domain words from your limited corpus & model into the same coordinate space as some older larger set of pretrained vectors that you like. There's an example of that process in a Gensim demo notebook using its utility `TranslationMatrix` class: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb

Comment: thank you very much.
what i try to do is to compare  semantic representation of w2v between different 
articles, so the whole point is to fine tune a model on 1 piece at a time and not expanding the corpus...I dont know if it's possible though

Comment: How large are the articles? Are you following a process that's been demonstrated elsewhere? There may not be enough text, or contrasting word usage, between individual articles to make this a sensible analysis. What's the ultimate goal that motivates this sort of comparison?

Comment: this is actually some research i am doing that i thought would be interesting...I try to understand what kind of semantic understanding is being learned by the w2v model in a deeper way than just distance between interchangeable words. i want to investigate what kind of insights such a model can get about relations between whole texts. for example, I would expect that in religious writings the words god and state will be closer than in writings about law, therefore some separability between the categories could be attained..(but separability is not the final goal, there are other models for )

Comment: That sounds interesting, but note that  word2vec requires many contrasting examples of a word's usage, in varying contexts, to start to give a word meaningful coordinates. Thus, individual articles of just hudreds to thousands may not be enough text to consistnely detect & reflect the patterns you're seeking. (With smaller amounts of text, patterns you see may be phantoms of either the model's initialization or somewhat arbitrary reflections of a single text's idiosyncratic word-to-word choices. Comparing larger multitext corpora, with many examples of anywords of interest, could help.)

Comment: Ultimately, you'll have to try it, with various texts & settings, to see if it shows insight. And you might not need to improvise any sort of harder-to-characterize fine-tuning to do comparisons. Totally-separate models, each sufficiently trained on different corpora, might in the differences of word-to-word distances or relative-rankings of neighbors (among some set of shared words) give the indicators you need.

Comment: But a thing to beware: raw cosine-similarity values generally *don't* have an absolute interpretation, like "words of 0.7 cosine-similarity are 70% alike". Their effective ranges vary a lot by other model parameterizations & factors like count of known words. As a vivid example, you can use the same corpus to train a 100d model & a 300d model. Both may show highly-alike & reasonable lists of most-similar words for a target word. But the cosine-similarity of the exact same nearest-neighbor word can be very different. The relevant signal is rankings & comparisons within the same model.

Comment: Interesting. My original thought was to not only compare specific words, but compare whole “topographies”, distance between texts(by multiple words distance, and to try to maximise overlap). What distance metric to use is certainly a main issue. Standardisation of the models, like same dim and so on is of course very important. Thank you very much for the answers! I would really like to hear more of your opinion on the subject

Comment: And another question- regarding the usage of transfer learning. I get what you are saying about better corpus, but it would be of usage I think if I could tune a relevant model on specific article(in case of a short one). Eventually, w2v is a network, for my understanding. Do you think that trying to utilise it via keras or something like this could open a path toward transfer learning(which is not available via genism?

Comment: My sense of word2vec is that an "article" won't have enough text to usefully fine-tune existing words, just like it doesn't have enough text to train its own model. I could be wrong – it might be possible to do something useful, depending on your exact corpus & goals – but I'm not familiar with any writeups showing a process for doing the kind of fine-tuning you're talking about & getting interesting results, so don't have a basis for suggestions.

Comment: If you're going to improvise your own experimental process, choosing whether to build on Keras or Gensim would depend on exactly what kind of process you want to implement & your comfort/familiarity with the codebases. You'd likely want to start with a working word2vec model in the traditional usage style, then add your new steps/functions.